# How to convert EOT font to TTF

Tags: fonts, console, file-conversion

Does somebody know a font conversion utility which is able to convert EOT fonts to ttf?

Comment: [onlinefontconverter.com](https://onlinefontconverter.com) Can convert eot to most popular formats